# How to update content of a ModalBottomSheet from parent while active

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a custom button which takes in a list of items. When it is pressed, it opens a modal bottom sheet and passes that list to the bottom sheet.

However, When the buttons items change it doesn't update the items in the bottom sheet.

How can I achieve this effect.

Simple example

```
ButtonsPage
     |
Button(items: initialItems)
     |
BottomSheet(items: initialItems)

** After a delay, setState is called in ButtonsPage with newItems, thereby sending newItems to the button

ButtonsPage
     |
Button(items: newItems)
     | ## Here, the bottom sheet is open. I want it to update initialItems to be newItems in the bottom sheet

BottomSheet(items: initialItems -- should be newItems)
```

Code Sample

This is my select field which, as shown, receives a list `items` and when it is pressed it opens a bottom sheet and sends the items received to the bottom sheet.

```
class PaperSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<dynamic> items;

  PaperSelect({
    this.items,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PaperSelectState createState() => _PaperSelectState();
}

class _PaperSelectState extends State<PaperSelect> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: widget.disabled ? null : () => _showBottomSheet(context),
        child: Container(
            
        ),
    );
  }

  void _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => BottomSheet(
        items: widget.items,
       ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

After some time (a network call), `items` is updated in the parent Widget of `PaperSelect`. `PaperSelect` then updates and receives the new items.

```
class BottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic items;

  BottomSheet({
    this.items,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _BottomSheetState();
  }
}

class _BottomSheetState extends State<BottomSheet> {
  dynamic items;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print(widget.items);
    items = widget.items;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(items==null) return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
          width: 140.0,
          height: 140.0,
          child: PaperLoader()
      ),
    );

    if(items==-1) return Text("Network Error");

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => ListTile(
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              title: Text('')
            )
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

Now, I want to send the updated data to the bottom sheet. However, it doesn't work because the ModalBottomSheet is already open.

How can I get around this?

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand the problem. I assume your problem relates to the content of your BottomSheet being created using a builder in `showBottomSheet` with one set of items, but when those items change the bottom sheet is not updated? (since the builder won't rerun). Is this correct? Maybe you could show some code or even a simple repro case on dartpad :-)

Comment: That is correct. Exactly

Comment: Hi, do you know any solution? @herbert

Comment: can you show the code of your bottom sheet?

Comment: I updated the question. PTAL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume here that items is a `List<String>`, since you did not specify that at all. (You should generally not use `dynamic` in most cases, because it does not do any type checking at all). Anyway,

One thing you could do (beside countless others) is pass in a `ValueNotifier<List<String>>` instead of a `List<String>` and then user that with a `ValueListenableBuilder` in your bottom sheet. like:

```dart
// in the caller
    final itemsNotifier = ValueNotifier(items);


// in your bottom sheet
    ValueListenableBuilder<List<String>>(
      valueListenable: itemsNotifier,
      builder: (context, snapshot, child) {
        final items = snapshot.data;
        // build your list
      },
    )
```

then every time you would change `itemsNotifier.value = [...]` your items would rebuild.

Note when updating `itemsNotifier.value`: It must not be done inside `build`/`didUpdateWidget`/etc. so if this is the case you might use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() => itemsNotifier.value = ... )` to postpone updating the value until after the current build phase.

Comment: Where will I add this `final itemsNotifier = ValueNotifier(items);`...initState or build?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work...It is a list of Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: in `initState`, otherwise you would not retain a reference to the right object. The above code works also with a Map<String, ...> ...obviously works with any kind of object..

Comment: Do you know of any other solution? Thanks for trying

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the fault of the solution. Make a simple reproduction of your porblem and i'll can try to fix it for you. But I can't just guess your whole code. For example use code pen https://codepen.io/pen/editor/flutter or on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ by sharing via gist.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jayaikendu/pen/pogGOBm  Please take a look

Comment: here you go: https://codepen.io/hpoul/pen/mdVvzOK .. there was just one more problem. You created the ValueNotifier in the inner widget and updated it on build() which would not work, because it would synchronously try to rebuild the bottom sheet. that's why an additional `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` is required. I think it would be nicer to move the `ValueNotifier` a level higher, and use a `ValueListenableBuilder` in `PaperSelect` as well, which could be stateless then i guess.

Comment: Thanks a million. Especially for your patience

Comment: you are welcome. I've updated the answer. maybe you could accept it.

Comment: If I don't specify the type, ie. instead of  `List<String>` I put `List<dynamic>` will it still work?

Comment: As long as you do not introduce any type errors it will work. But seriously, never ever use dynamic.. imho it's just a cause of bugs because you lose essentially the complete static type checking, which is a bad idea

Comment: Whenever I add a uniqueKey to the paperselect (or any kind of key) it doesn't work...Any idea as to why? Demonstrated here https://codepen.io/jayaikendu/pen/pogGOBm